# Calculating the Custom Time with Back Tracking the record

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to calculate the timing by back tracking in SQL Server but am not able to find a reliable way to do it.

The table I am using is

```
ID Student StudentLeader TestTime
1  132897  132897        1440
2  132555  132897        120
3  132475  132897        126
4  132659  132897        100
```

I am trying to calculate the timing as below

```
Student TimeBeforeTest TimeAfterTest
132897  1440           0
132555  120            246 = (SUM 2+3)
132475  126            226 = (SUM 3+4) 
132659  100            0
```

Can anybody please guide me how to do it

Comment: What's the logic? What do you mean backtracking? Why should #2 and #3 be included but not #1 or #4? You can use aggregate and windowing functions with the `OVER()` clause, eg `SUM() OVER(...)` to calculate running totals, or retrieve the "previous" or "next" value in a partition, but you *do* need to identify those partitions

Comment: In general, the problem of identifying related regions in a sequence of results is called the `gaps and islands problem`. You'll find a lot of articles that explain how to identify gaps or islands before aggregating. In this case you're looking for an island of test times defined by ... something that wasn't explained

Comment: Back tracking means getting the previous records value and adding it to the current record value, Why should #2 and #3 be included but not #1 or #4? -- The logic for calculation is given like that only

Comment: That's not backtracking. That's retrieving previous results. That's what `OVER()` does. Backtracking is one way of implementing this. Again, what's the logic? If you don't know that, you won't be able to write *any* query. `Just add 2 and 4` isn't adequate - you could just write a `WHERE ID IN (2,3)` to sum only those rows. You can use the `LAG` and `LEAD` values to get the "previous" or "next" values in a set, but where do you stop? You can write `LEAD(TestTime) + TestTime as TimeAfterTest` but why should #4 return 0 instead of  100?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Since after #4 Student there is no student the `TimeAfterTest` is 0 the logic is to calculate the `TimeAfterTest` only for the in between students

Comment: Have you tried LEAD or LAG?

Comment: No Not yet, I am not aware of `LAG` and `LEAD` have to do some research on it before using it

Comment: Just [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Instead of Comment can you please make it as an Answer I will accept it